# Audit change log not recording not Primary key on Create

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created an Audit Change log, from an example found here https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/audit-trail-implementation-in-aspnet-core/

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }


    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        AddAuditLog();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    
    private void AddAuditLog()
    {
        var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        var auditEntries = new List<AuditEntry>();
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (entry.Entity is AuditLog || entry.State == EntityState.Detached || entry.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
                continue;
            var auditEntry = new AuditEntry(entry);
            auditEntry.TableName = entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
            auditEntry.UserId = userId;
            auditEntries.Add(auditEntry);
            foreach (var property in entry.Properties)
            {
                string propertyName = property.Metadata.Name;
                    if (property.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
                    {
                        auditEntry.KeyValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        continue;
                    }
                    switch (entry.State)
                    {
                        case EntityState.Added:
                            auditEntry.AuditType = AuditType.Create;
                            auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Deleted:
                            auditEntry.AuditType = AuditType.Delete;
                            auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Modified:
                            if (property.IsModified)
                            {
                                auditEntry.ChangedColumns.Add(propertyName);
                                auditEntry.AuditType = AuditType.Update;
                                auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                                auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }
        foreach (var auditEntry in auditEntries)
        {
            AuditLogs.Add(auditEntry.ToAudit());
        }
    }
```

All works as expected, except the Primary Key (Id) is not logged on CREATE.
All the primary keys of new records are recorded in the log as {"Id":-2147482647}, for some reason.

Is it possible to log the newly created Key?
Or is the problem that the Key is only created once the SaveChanges is completed and therefore could not be logged.

In the example referenced above the author seems to have it working

Comment: You need to get the DB generated values after saving the changes: https://www.meziantou.net/entity-framework-core-history-audit-table.htm

Comment: @meziantou thank you. I amended my code and have the Id saving. Are you not creating a loop by OnAfterSaveChanges calling SaveChangesAsync() again?

Comment: It should be safe as there is no new changes to save

Comment: @meziantou thank you very much, work perfectly. If you post as an answer, I can mark accepted.

Comment: I've posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work with database generated values. You need to read their values after saving entities to the database.

Original post (with more details): [Entity Framework Core: History / Audit table](https://www.meziantou.net/entity-framework-core-history-audit-table.htm?utm_medium=social&utm_source=stackoverflow)

```cs
// https://www.meziantou.net/entity-framework-core-history-audit-table.htm
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var auditEntries = OnBeforeSaveChanges();
        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
        await OnAfterSaveChanges(auditEntries);
        return result;
    }

    private List<AuditEntry> OnBeforeSaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        var auditEntries = new List<AuditEntry>();
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (entry.Entity is Audit || entry.State == EntityState.Detached || entry.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
                continue;

            var auditEntry = new AuditEntry(entry);
            auditEntry.TableName = entry.Metadata.GetTableName();
            auditEntries.Add(auditEntry);

            foreach (var property in entry.Properties)
            {
                if (property.IsTemporary)
                {
                    // value will be generated by the database, get the value after saving
                    auditEntry.TemporaryProperties.Add(property);
                    continue;
                }

                string propertyName = property.Metadata.Name;
                if (property.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
                {
                    auditEntry.KeyValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                    continue;
                }

                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        if (property.IsModified)
                        {
                            auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                            auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var auditEntry in auditEntries.Where(_ => !_.HasTemporaryProperties))
        {
            Audits.Add(auditEntry.ToAudit());
        }

        return auditEntries.Where(_ => _.HasTemporaryProperties).ToList();
    }

    private Task OnAfterSaveChanges(List<AuditEntry> auditEntries)
    {
        if (auditEntries == null || auditEntries.Count == 0)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        foreach (var auditEntry in auditEntries)
        {
            foreach (var prop in auditEntry.TemporaryProperties)
            {
                if (prop.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
                {
                    auditEntry.KeyValues[prop.Metadata.Name] = prop.CurrentValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    auditEntry.NewValues[prop.Metadata.Name] = prop.CurrentValue;
                }
            }

            Audits.Add(auditEntry.ToAudit());
        }

        return SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```